# How to merge one branch to another without some files?

Tags: git, git-merge

I've got two branches - development and master. I'm also using Catch2 framework for unit testing. Catch2 is on the development branch but when it comes to releasing a version to master, I don't want these files to go there.

Is there a command which allows me to "lock" some files on one branch? 
Let's say it looks like that:
**Development**
- Source Code
- Unit Testing Code

MERGE

**Master**
- Source Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the [cherry-pick](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-cherry-pick.html) command to get individual commits from one branch.

If the change(s) you want are not in individual commits, then use the method shown here to [split the commit into individual commits](http://plasmasturm.org/log/530/). Roughly speaking, you use `git rebase -i` to get the original commit to edit, then `git reset HEAD^` to selectively revert changes, then `git commit` to commit that bit as a new commit in the history.

[There is another nice method here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130727101330/http://magazine.redhat.com:80/2008/05/02/shipping-quality-code-with-git/) in Red Hat Magazine, where they use `git add --patch` or possibly `git add --interactive` which allows you to add just parts of a hunk, if you want to split different changes to an individual file (search in that page for "split").

Having split the changes, you can now cherry-pick just the ones you want.

Comment: So I would have to do it every time I'd like to merge?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. But there might be better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git checkout --patch <branch> <file>`
Make sure you are on master branch.